# strncpy() segmentation fault: shady strtok() manipulations?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program that takes lines from the user and parses them for a homework assignment.
I am constrained to a certain amount of memory, so the variables I use below are the only ones I can use.

I get a segmentation fault with my code, and using gdb have found it originates with the strncpy() function call below. The only reason I can see for this happening is that something is wrong with str, caused by my use of strtok(). If someone could point out how I am using strtok() incorrectly or an alternate method of parsing the strings by whitespace without any added variables, I would really appreciate it.

The strings are of the format "00 COMMAND 0", I'm trying to put the last bit into the array, while preserving the COMMAND for later calculations. COMMAND will vary from 3 to 4 chars in length.

```
char str[11];
*count = 0;


while( scanf( "%[^\n]%*c", str ) == 1 )
{
    printf( "\n%s\n", str );
    strtok( str, " " );
    strtok( NULL, " " );
    memory[*count] = atoi( strtok( NULL, " " ) );


    strtok( str, " " );
    strncpy( str, strtok( NULL, " " ), sizeof( str ) );
```

Comment: Regardless of what else you are doing, `atoi( strtok` is always risky because `strtok` could return NULL. Check the return value before passing to `atoi` (or `strncpy`).

Comment: Also be aware that `strncpy` does not null-terminate its buffer if the source string is long enough to fill it up; so if you want to later access `str` as a string then it would be wise to put a `'\0'` on the end, or even better, avoid `strncpy` altogether.

Comment: I would avoid strncpy altogether, as I am aware of it's issues, but the compiler settings I'm required to use don't support the alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strtok changes the str by adding '\0' characters at the end of the tokens. So the second time you call strtok with str as a parameter, it will only see the "00" part of the string.
The easiest fix is to save off the command part the first time through the tokenization:

```
strtok( str, " " );
strncpy( str, strtok( NULL, " " ), sizeof( str ) );
memory[*count] = atoi( strtok( NULL, " " ) );
```

Of course, you should also be checking the return values of strtok to make sure you aren't passed incorrect input.

Edit - oops. I didn't realize you wanted to store the command back into str. It should be safe to copy the command part back into str as it must be shorter than the first parameter + the command. It does look a bit dodgy though. You would be better off with another pointer variable for the command. It is only another 4-8 bytes bytes (depending on your system).

```
char *command;
strtok( str, " " );
command = strtok( NULL, " " );
memory[*count] = atoi( strtok( NULL, " " ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the first thing to do is capture and print the return values from `strtok()`, or to check that they aren't null when you were expecting a non-null return.

Given the second part of the code:

```
strtok(str, " ");
strncpy(str, strtok(NULL, " "), sizeof(str));
```

You are using `strncpy()` to copy a segment of the string `str` over itself.  That is undefined behaviour:

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

When you invoke undefined behaviour, anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the second token pointer to 'str'.  No need to copy.

```
printf( "\n%s\n", str );
strtok( str, " " ); /* apparently you don't care about this token */
str = strtok( NULL, " " );  /* 'str' now points to COMMAND */
memory[*count] = atoi( strtok( NULL, " " ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unless I'm mistaken, we can't assign to arrays like that, that's why I was dicking about with strncpy in the first place.